# H2 and flyway crush on tests after upgrade from gradle 4 to 6

Tags: spring-boot, h2, flyway

I am in the process of upgrading from gradle 4 to 6.
This forced me to upgrade many stuff like spring, h2, mySql connector, etc..

Now I have this problem:
on runtime, using MySQL all works fine.
but on tests, I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in com.bluerbn.wallet.infra.SpringTestConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
Migration V9__fixIndex.sql failed
------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42S22
Error Code : 42122
Message    : Column "INDEX" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP INDEX ACC_INDEX [42122-200]
Location   : db/migration/V9__fixIndex.sql (/Users/.../resources/db/migration/V9__fixIndex.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : ALTER TABLE table1 DROP INDEX ACC_INDEX
```

This is an old script that was working fine before the upgrade.

**versions:**

- spring boot:  2.3.0
- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:6.4.1 (though in gradle I put 6.4.2)
- com.h2database:h2:1.4.200
- mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H2 since the version 1.4.200 allows MySQL-style `ALTER TABLE tableName DROP INDEX indexName` only in MySQL compatibility mode. In 1.4.199 and older versions this invalid (for H2) command was incorrectly accepted in all modes.

You need to append `;MODE=MySQL` to JDBC URL for H2.

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE;INIT=create schema if not exists \\"public\"\\; SET SCHEMA public;

This is myURL

Comment: This exception clearly means that H2 is not running in MySQL compatibility mode. If you don't have `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` or something like it (AFAIK, this annotation is deprecated), your testing configuration is ignored by Spring.

Comment: BTW, `"public"` is not the same as `public` with default settings, you may want to use `;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE` instead of such `INIT` command.